# bash add leading zeros to the count while number

Tags: bash, numbers, padding, zero, digits

I have the bash while loop using an initial count.
I want to add `%03d` three digits to the count so that the output is like:

```
folder001
folder002
```

my code is:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    input_file=$1
    csv_file=$2

    count=1
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
      input_dir="./res/folder"%03d"$count/input"
      output_dir="./res/folder"%03d"$count/output"
      results_dir="./res/all_results_png/png"

      mkdir -p "$input_dir" "$output_dir"
      printf '%s\n' "$line" > "$input_dir/myline.csv"
      find $output_dir -name image_"folder$count*".png -exec cp {} $results_dir \;

      ((count++))
    done < "$csv_file"
```

i add `%03d` to the code above as you can see, but it is printing it literally. 
what am I missing here?
thanks

### upadte

added an update which is:
trying to do a `find` of the files with the pattern

```
image_"folder$count*".png
```

how can I reflect the three digits changes in the find command as well?

Comment: What do you want achieve? Asking because youre creating the `$output_dir` but not using it (it remains as an empty dir).

Comment: @jm666 i am doing some other running of scripts that i have omitted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `printf` to achieve this. Here's an example:

```
AMD$ cat File.sh
#!/bin/bash

count=25
input_dir=$(printf "/res/folder%03d/input" $count)
echo $input_dir

AMD$ ./File.sh
/res/folder025/input
```

For the update in your question, you can do the same logic.

```
filename=$(printf "image_folder%03d" $count)
find . -name "$filename.png"
```

In your case:

```
find $output_dir -name "$filename.png" -exec cp {} $results_dir \;
```

Comment: thanks, this is working, however i added an update, which is trying to find the files with the same pattern, but again we need those three digit pattern. how can I do it? could you please update your answer? thanks

Comment: Hi. The above solves my issue but the solution seems overly complicated. Is there a simpler syntax?? `tr -s ' ' < file_V$(printf "%02d" $i).txt > file_V$(printf "%02d" $((++i))).txt`. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `printf` to get formatted output. Replace first 2 lines inside `while` line to this:

```
printf -v input_dir './res/folder%03d/input' $count
printf -v output_dir '/res/folder%03d/output' $count
```

If `count=3` then above 2 lines will effectively be:

```
input_dir="./res/folder003/input"
output_dir="./res/folder003/output"
```

Comment: then my variables are not resolved... when later i use these variables, the reference is not clear... missing.

Comment: Right after these `printf` command, examine variables using `declare -p input_dir output_dir` command and see what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

Other way - try this:

```bash
export count=12 
export ZEROS=0000

echo "file${ZEROS:${#count}}${count}"
```

out:

```
file0012
```